# Is there a way to eliminate y scrollers on shiny output in rmarkdown?

Tags: html, r, shiny, knitr, r-markdown

I have an interactive doc in rmarkdown using shiny apps.

My YAML:

```
---
title: "Shiny HTML Doc"
author: "theforestecologist"
date: "Apr 13, 2017"
output:  html_document
runtime: shiny
---
```

I generate a number of shiny apps throughout this document, but they all are too long (i.e., they all require y scrollers to view their entirety.

I know I can add options = list(height = ###,width = ###) within the shinyApp function in my code chunk to control individual rendered apps, but I want my readers to see my shiny code (sans messy option controls).

So my desired approach is to control all of the shiny app outputs at once.

- Specifically, is there a way to make it so they each can have variable heights, but each one be fully pictured (i.e., not needing a vertical (y) scroller)?

---

**Example Code:**

````
---
title: "Shiny HTML Doc"
author: "theforestecologist"
date: "Apr 13, 2017"
output:  html_document
runtime: shiny
---

I have an interactive shiny doc with app outputs of varying heights. 
By default, they all have the same height, which is too small of a value
(and thus creates the need for vertical scrolling bars).

##### **Example 1**

```{r, eval=TRUE,echo=FALSE}
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(  
  titlePanel("Ex1"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "type", label = "Plant Type", choices = levels(CO2$Type), 
                         selected = levels(CO2$Type))  
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput(outputId = "scatter.plot")  
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$scatter.plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(uptake ~ conc, data = CO2, type = "n")
    points(uptake ~ conc, data = CO2[CO2$Type  %in% c(input$type),])
    title(main = "Plant Trends")
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The output of the next example is longer and therefore needs a larger height assignment to get rid of the scroll bar. 

##### **Example 2**

```{r, eval=TRUE,echo=FALSE}
ui <- fluidPage(  
  titlePanel("Ex1"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      div(style = "padding:0px 0px 450px 0px;",
          checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "type", label = "Plant Type", choices = levels(CO2$Type), 
                             selected = levels(CO2$Type))
      )  
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput(outputId = "scatter.plot")  
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$scatter.plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(uptake ~ conc, data = CO2, type = "n")
    points(uptake ~ conc, data = CO2[CO2$Type  %in% c(input$type),])
    title(main = "Plant Trends")
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```
````

Comment: How about a more complete example? Should be easy.

Comment: @MikeWise example added. Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!